# `which`, but all

Tags: path

I think most are familiar with the `which` command, and I use it frequently. I just ran into a situation where I'm curious not just which command is first in my path, but how many and where *all* the commands in all my paths are. I tried the which man page (typing `man which` made me laugh), but didn't see anything.

Comment: On my system, it's the first thing listed on the man page: `which --all`.

Comment: On mine (linux) it's only `which -a`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

On some systems, **`which -a`** shows all matches. If your shell is bash or zsh¹, you can use `type` instead: `type foo` shows the first match and `type -a foo` shows all matches. The three commands `type`, `which` and `whence` do mostly the same thing; they differ between shells and operating systems in availability, options, and what exactly they report. `type` is always available and shows all possible command-like names (aliases, keywords, shell built-ins, functions, and external commands).

The only fully portable way to display all matches is to parse `$PATH` yourself. Here's a shell script that does this. If you make it a shell function, make sure to enclose the function body in parentheses (so that the change to `IFS` and `set -f` don't escape the function), and change `exit` to `return`.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -f       # disable globbing
IFS=:        # break words at : only
not_found=1
for d in $PATH; do
  if [ -f "$d/$x" ] && [ -x "$d/$x" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$d/$x"
    not_found=0
  fi
done
exit $not_found
```

¹ 
<sub>Or ksh 93, according to the documentation, though ksh 93s+ 2008-01-31 only prints the first match when I try.</sub>

Comment: That `sh` code doesn't work properly if there are empty components in `$PATH`. Also note that `$IFS` is a field _delimiter_ (in POSIX shells at least) while in `$PATH`, colon is used as a field _separator_. See the `which` script found on Debian for a correct implementation.

Comment: the `type` builtin in `ksh93u+ 2012-08-01` seems to work properly.

Comment: Don't forget about `whereis`

Answer (score 6):

The --all or -a flag will show you all matches in your path, and aliases (at least on Fedora, Ubuntu and CentOS):

```
which -a which
```

On AIX and Solaris, this will get you close:

```
echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:/ /g' | \
while read -r p; do find "$p" -type f -name "which"; done
```

Comment: You need double quotes around parameter substitutions, otherwise the script won't work if `$PATH` contains whitespace or shell globbing characters. `read -r` is necessary to cope with backslashes. This is not a good method because `find` will take a long time and may return spurious matches if a directory in `$PATH` contains subdirectories. Fortunately, `find` is not useful here; see my answer.

Comment: I knew find felt wrong since it would certainly be slow in nested directories. Globbing and spaces in $PATH? eww. But you're right (though you were nice enough not to say as much): my one liner was poorly written.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a `which` supporting `-a`, or `whence` available, roll your own:

```
#!/bin/sh -f

IFS=":"
for PART in $PATH
do
  if test -x "$PART/$1"
  then
    echo $PART/$1
  fi
done
```

Comment: You're missing `set -f` to turn off globbing on the unprotected `$PATH`. `test -f` isn't sufficient since only executable files are wanted here; you need `test -x`. Hmm, I realize I forgot the regular file test in my script.

Comment: @Gilles: edited according to your tips. I'm all for correctness, but I find `whence README.txt` as unlikely as `whence "file* wi?h we!rd name"`. Just trying to show how easy it is to traverse `$PATH`.

Comment: This was the only script that worked for me in OmniOS r151030 (OpenSolaris fork). #!/bin/sh -x helpful for troubleshooting - is there a way to omit the last echo? It's a repeat.

Answer (score 0):

ksh and zsh have "whence" as a shell built-in.  `whence -a` does what you want under zsh:

```
 7:27AM 7 % whence -a cat
/usr/bin/cat
/bin/cat
/usr/bin/cat
/bin/cat
```

I have to clean up PATH in zsh, I have lots of duplicates in it. `whence -a` works differently under ksh:

```
$ whence -a cat
cat is a tracked alias for /usr/bin/cat
```

I have to say, that seems like a potentially useful behavior, too.