# how is whence different than which?

Tags: debian, which

I read [`which`, but all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9683/which-but-all/) but I cannot really get the difference. I am running zsh 5.4.2 on 64-bit debian-buster. Both which and whence are shell-builtins .

Can people point out where whence would be more appropriate than which and vice-versa ?

```
/home/shirish> zsh --version
zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu)

/home/shirish> type -a which
which is a shell builtin
which is /usr/bin/which
which is /bin/which

/home/shirish> type -a whence
whence is a shell builtin
```

Answer (score 33):

`which` was a csh command (well a `csh` script that read your `~/.cshrc`), `whence` was the Korn shell's answer to `csh`'s `which`, `type` the Bourne shell one, `command -v/V` the POSIX one...

`zsh` implements `ksh`'s `whence` with a few extensions, but also provides a `which` alias for the csh junkies and `type`/`command -v/V` for POSIX compliance which are just the same command but with different default behaviour.

- `which` is `whence -c` (`c` for `csh`)
- `type` is `whence -v` (more verbose `whence`)
- `where` is `whence -ca`
- POSIX `command -v` is like `whence`
- POSIX `command -V` is like `whence -v`

You'll find some more information (though in a bit of a messy way, sorry) at [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: @dr_, I've reverted your edit. There is no `whereis` builtin in zsh. There is a `whereis` command on BSDs or in `util-linux`, but that has nothing to do with `whence -ca`. See `info zsh where` for the documentation about `zsh`'s `where`.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the edit. I did not realize your third paragraph referred exclusively to `zsh`.  I was referring to Bash.

Answer (score 1):

**whence [ -vcfpam ] name ...**
For each name, indicate how it would be interpreted if used as a command name. The `-v` flag produces a more verbose report. The `-c` flag prints the results in a csh-like format and takes precedence over `-v`. The `-f` flag causes the contents of a shell function to be displayed, which would otherwise not happen unless the `-c` flag were used. The `-p` flag does a path search for name even if it is an alias, reserved word, shell function or builtin. The `-a` flag does a search for all occurrences of name throughout the command path. With the `-m` flag, the arguments are taken as patterns (which should be quoted), and the information is displayed for each command matching one of these patterns.

**which [ -pam ] name ...**
Same as whence -c.

You should check the [zsh manual](http://bolyai.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_17.html)